# Preparing for a software internship interview

Tags: interviewing, resume, software-industry, internship, dress-code

I'm a 2nd year computer science student and have an in person interview with Yahoo in a couple of days for a co-op (internship) position. This is my first ever software related interview, ever. This is going to be an in-person interview, and quite frankly, I don't know what to expect.

I want to be as prepared as possible though. What kind of questions should I anticipate? How should I dress? Any other tips, or small details that you think a novice like me should be aware of? Would greatly appreciate any advice you guys can offer, thank you!

Comment: 1. Ask directly your contact at yahoo what to wear; 2. Ask for the interview questions: http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Yahoo-Intern-Interview-Questions-EI_IE5807.0,5_KO6,12.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I am working in the financial services field now, I have been interviewed for several technological / programming positions due to having been a CS minor during college.

> What kind of questions should I anticipate

The basic interview questions are fair game such as some of the following:

- Please tell me about your background / yourself
- Why are you interested in this position
- How does your experience match the (specific required expertise here)

Depending on the specific position you are seeking, there can be other more technical questions testing your hard skills (coding, programming etc)

> How should I dress?

I would err on the side of conservatism and dress in business formal with dress shirt and tie. It is a sign of respect to your employer and shows you are taking this interview as seriously as possible.

Do check [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/83/selecting-interview-attire-for-a-technical-job-interview) for additional detail regarding dress code for technical interviews.