# 27 years old, shall I wear tie and suit in my first day at my new company?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry

I am moving to a new firm, I already finish all the interviews and the tests and got accepted.

I am wondering if in my first day, it is good to wear tie and suit (or just suit) or something less formal.

I am 27 years old and my job title is Developer.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Thanks for correcting my typos

Comment: Did you see anyone wearing suit and tie while you were interviewing there? Why are you asking us, and not asking your point of contact at the company?

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan to be honest, I didn't see a tie and a suit in the interviews there, I saw men with genes and Tshirt (it was summer), I don't know what a point of contact is, but I do contact the HR always and I am shy to ask them this question

Comment: @user259935 Go by what you see. Wear something similar to whatever your interviewers wore.

Comment: If you wear a suit, they will probably not recognize (or respect) you as a developer, because they will expect someone who looks like a bum.

Comment: VTC. Other questions have covered the general topic before, what *your* dress code is is something to ask your employer.

Comment: @Lilienthal could you show me this topic please?

Comment: @user2059935 Have a look at the "RELATED" questions on the right of this page in the sidebar or look at the questions in the [dress code tag](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dress-code).

Comment: Related: [Selecting interview attire for a technical job interview](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/83/selecting-interview-attire-for-a-technical-job-interview)

Answer (score 7):

> I am wondering if in my first day, it is good to wear tie and suit (or
>   just suit) or something less formal.

I don't know any Developers who wear ties and/or suits at work these days. In my area, the norms seem to run from anything goes (shorts, flip-flops, etc), to business casual (shoes, khakis and a shirt with buttons and a collar).

But it would depend on the culture in your locale and at your workplace. It's possible (although unlikely) that formal dress is the norm at your new shop.

If you interviewed on-site, you could have looked around and see how others were dressed - that would be a clue. Similarly, how the folks that interviewed you were dressed is a clue.

But if you still aren't sure, you could do what I did when I was young and unsure. Call the office. Talk to the receptionist, HR or office manager, and ask how other Developers are dressed. While it might feel awkward to ask that question, you are likely to get some friendly help, just as I did.

Comment: In the interview, the men were wearing genes and tshirt (it was summer), not too casul of course but sure not a tie, I know that in the normal situation i will never, neither my college, will wear tie and suit, but i am asking about the first day. the first day matters in many things (smile, handshare, eye contract, .... ) and cloths

Comment: I am really shy to ask the HR, it would be like a child action asking his mom what to wear in his first date

Comment: @user2059935 You don't ask what to wear exactly, you ask "what's the dress code?" It's a perfectly reasonable question to ask and nobody will think it odd. Certainly not as odd as wearing a suit and tie when everyone around you us in t-shirts.

Comment: if the interviewers were in jeans/tshirt you'd be massively overdressed.  If you want to look a bit nicer on your first day (eg for a badge photo), khaki's and a polo would be reasonable.  Beyond that you're going to start looking out of place.

Comment: @user2059935 you need to work on getting over your shyness. We don't know where you work or what their standards are, so how can we (strangers from around the world) possibly answer this question? Communication is critical in the workplace.  When you have a question about your job you need to address it with the persons who can best answer it. Call HR and ask them what the company dress code is.

Comment: I was at a local user group meeting and a dev was talking about customer visits at law firms in Washington D.C.  He said that not only was a suit and tie mandatory, you also need to be cognizant about the differences between summer and winter dress requirements.  So yes, locations like that *do* exist.

Comment: To extend - khakis, button down shirt, and a sport jacket.  You can quickly remove the jacket.

Comment: I don't know any suit and tie developers either

Comment: Emphasis here on the developer culture, get to know it and dress accordingly.  I have seen a few suit and tie places for developers still.  I recall a few law firms big enough to have their own developers requiring EVERYONE in business formal wear.

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts would be to dress the same as the manager you interviewed with was wearing during your interview.  If he was wearing slacks and an Oxford shirt, then you can start with that.  If he was wearing a Polo shirt and Khakis, then there's your target.

Try to stay consistent for a week, and take note of everyone else's dress.  If one person is wearing ripped jeans and flip-flops, that does not mean that everyone else gets to.

After a week, try to "fit in" with your group, but don't be afraid to dress a bit better.  If it's a jeans and T-Shirt shop, then make sure your jeans are clean, not torn, and don't be afraid to let the world know you have an iron.  Clean shoes that are in good shape are always better, no matter what the dress is.  Also - I guarantee no one wants to see your toenails.  Fit in, but fit in with style.

However:  T-Shirts are for music festivals, going to the gym, and days when you have to pull cables under the raised floor.  A polo is the minimum.

Comment: Did you mean to mention toe nails twice?

Comment: No, I had a much longer version initially, then realized I'd talked in a circle. :)

Comment: Unless there's something really funky going on with your toenails; wearing socks with sandals is worse than wearing sandals without.