# Is it acceptable dress in formal attire for an interview?

Tags: interviewing, dress-code

Generally speaking, I've always heard that you should dress nicely for an interview. Most advice I've heard from is that business casual should be the most casual you dress and that business professional or business formal is preferred. There has been a [question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/83/selecting-interview-attire-for-a-technical-job-interview) on whether or not you should always wear a suit or not.

However I do not have an appropriate business suit but I do have a Tuxedo jacket and several different options of formal pants and vests.  Would it be acceptable if I wore this to an interview for a technical job?  Is doing this likely to cause any problems?

As far as this being primarily opinion based, it is not anymore opinion based that the question I linked, nor more opinion based than many questions on this site. It is asking about established norms for a certain situation and can be answered by professional experience.

Comment: What job are you applying for? There are certain jobs where tuxedo would be not only appropriate, but in fact required.

Comment: Showing up in an attire that nobody wear for work will backfire on you. Not just as inappropriate but as completely weird

Comment: If you're applying for a job where you would be expected to wear a tuxedo regularly, then it seems appropriate. Otherwise it could come off as excessive and more like a costume.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense: can you list a few jobs that require a tuxedo?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't truly believe anyone is really considering this.

Comment: The rule I tried to use when applying for jobs is to wear the most formal attire you would expect to wear on the job. That might mean what you would plan to wear if representing your employer in a formal meeting with a client or at a trade show booth. If you would never wear a tux on the job, don't wear it to the interview.

Comment: How does this question not fall under the very first topic? "Finding employment (resumes/cv/cover letters, recruiters, hiring-managers, >>>interviews<<<, negotiations, etc.)" The question is specifically about interview attire. Just because people aren't taking the question seriously doesn't mean it can't be a serious question.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this as I can't tell the difference between a suit and a tuxedo and this information might be valuable to me in the future. I would totally wear a tuxedo to an interview if I owned one and felt some weird need to dress formally for it. (Although I might change my mind based on the answers)

Comment: @Erik you can't tell the difference between a tuxedo and a suit? Another name for Tuxedo would be _dinner suit_. If you're wearing satin and have a bow tie don't go to an interview, go out for an evening meal. This kind of information is widely available on the Internet. I'm not exactly sure of the terms on Workplace but on SO if you don't show research and/or any attempt at finding the answer the question is generally off-topic.

Comment: @Bugs the most formal set of clothing I own is a button-up shirt & jeans, so no I really wouldn't be able to tell the difference between those two.

Comment: @Erik my point is you can [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=should+I+wear+a+tuxedo+to+an+interview&safe=active&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=1C3vWN2EIufFgAbDs5kQ#safe=active&q=difference+between+work+suit+and+dinner+suit&spf=1) and your answer would be right [there](http://www.mytuxedocatalog.com/blog/tuxedo-questions-and-answers-what-is-the-difference-between-a-tuxedo-and-a-suit/).

Comment: [This question is **being discussed on meta**.](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4447/)

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings yes, i own a tuxedo, and considering it is considered formal wear, i didnt know whether or not it would be okay to wear to an interview

Comment: I think this version will be more acceptable.  Calling the tux out in the title probably biases the question.  Referring to it as formal wear in the title will hopefully avoid that.

Comment: I think it's important to draw the distinction between "tuxedo" and "formal attire". The latter could include something like a business suit, which would be acceptable for an interview. A tuxedo would not.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere i do now, however i think it is still a decent question as others have also expressed that they didnt know and would like it to remain to help others who might have the same question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<sup>I would first like to say I am taking this question seriously. Any humor found in this answer is not to belittle or insult the OP.</sup>

> *I own a tuxedo and have always liked the look of wearing one, but would it be considered proper to wear one to a technical interview for a development role?*

I have to agree that I also like the look of wearing a tuxedo but I would have to say **NO** this is not suitable. This reminds me of [Step Brothers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0838283/):

[image]

<sup>For context of the Step Brothers reference check out the [scene (**NSFW**)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bbV_Q2sfIpg).</sup>

The definition of a [Tuxedo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuxedo) is:

> A dinner jacket (British English) or tuxedo (American English, also colloquially known as "tux"), dinner suit, or DJ is a semi-formal evening suit distinguished primarily by satin or grosgrain facings on the jacket's lapels and buttons and a similar stripe along the outseam of the trousers.

I've done a quick [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Can+I+wear+tuxedo+for+interview%3F&safe=active&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=eU7vWJnLCOGdgAaLgp7wCw#spf=1) search:

[Can I wear tuxedo for interview?](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-wear-tuxedo-for-interview):

> Tuxedo is classified as a highly formal, evening wear outfit. You will be considered a dandy, if you wear it to an interview.
>
> A business suit is ideally 2-piece with 2 or 3 buttons. A blazer would also do, if it is for a middle or junior level position. The workwear trends are moving towards Business Casual.
>
> It is okay to ask before hand, if the company has a dress code. It is also better to err on the conservative side, rather than be caught on the wrong foot, in being too casual. Dressing well and in an appropriate manner shows that you are taking the interview seriously.

---

> It depends upon the job you are interviewing for - perhaps it is appropriate for a narrow slice of interviews (maitre de?, symphony conductor?). But for the rest of us looking for gainful employmeant, a solid navy or charcoal suit, white shirt, red or blue tie, polished black dress shoes, is a far safer bet.

[Are tuxedo suits appropriate for a job interview?](https://www.quora.com/Are-tuxedo-suits-appropriate-for-a-job-interview):

> Not at all. a tuxedo is an ocassion wear meant to be worn in parties, award ceremonies, wedding and similar events. There are specified black tie events where tux are more or less norms.

---

> Absolutely not
> Unless the job is maitre d’ at a VERY upmarket hotel or restaurant where it will be the working uniform

---

> The tuxedo, or dinner suit, is for formal dinners and events only

It may also be helpful to know the [differences](http://www.jbsuits.com/blog/suit-vs-tux/) between a tuxedo and a suit:

[image]

On this article there is also a summary which again hightlights when it's appropriate to wear a tuxedo:

> Both suits and tuxedo are important elements of men’s wardrobe undeniably, and both of them have their own significance. Which one is better is always depend on upon the place or events it is expected to wear. Suits, as we highlighted above, are comparatively more common that’s why’s they are the best to wear daily at the office or formal gathering. **Tuxedo is the premier choice for semi-formal events like high school proms, black tie events, and weddings; it gives you a great opportunity to show your elegance and make yourself look unique.**

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

I'm sure there is much more out there about when and where you should wear a tuxedo but I would have to say in your case it would not be deemed appropriate.

<sup>If you do end up attending an interview in your tuxedo please do let us know how you got on.</sup>

Comment: @JoeStrazzere no that's not what it says. That's slightly twisting the quote. You can make yourself look elegant and unique without having to turn up in a full tuxedo.

Comment: But as a general unwritten rule, you should always wear a suit were possible. A tuxedo is for formal dinner/evening wear.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere given the number of answers that suggest you shouldn't do anything out of the ordinary because you'll be cut from process, I'm getting the feeling that you indeed shouldn't strive to look unique when looking for a job. (Which is weird, because I'm pretty sure it'd help, but very few answers actually suggest it)

Comment: Contrary to the cited article, weddings (in the US at least) are most often *not* black tie events, and a tux would be out of place unless you're in the wedding party (in which case you'll generally be told *exactly* what to wear).

Comment: @Caleb to be honest that's generally the case in the U.K. I wouldn't wear a tux unless it was to a prestige event. Weddings, I would probably just wear my best suit.

Comment: @Erik [Gimmicks don't help you get a job](http://money.usnews.com/money/blogs/outside-voices-careers/2012/07/16/could-a-gimmick-get-you-a-job). We get a lot of questions about making your application stand out but the only correct way to do so is by writing an excellent cover letter and applying for jobs that match your profile. Most gimmicks won't result in an automatic no-hire but it's telling that they're always things that great candidates and high-performers simply do not do.

Comment: @Erik, you want to stand out based on your accomplishments. Standing out for looking substantially different is a quick way to the bottom of the pile  unless your accomplishments are far, far greater than anyone else you are competing with.  One of the things you are being judged on is your judgement and if you can't figure out how to dress appropriately for an interview, then your judgement becomes suspect.

Comment: @Erik, these are the types of things that I have seen make someone stand out in a positive way in an interview: extensive knowledge of their profession  demonstrated by in-depth answers well beyond the answers of their competitors, work samples especially ones that are far better than the competition's samples. Ability to discuss what they actually did on their current project and past projects (you would be amazed at how many people can't actually talk about their  work other than what they were responsible for). It's like the difference between A work and C work in school.

Answer (score 29):

You would be laughed at, if not to your face most certainly behind your back.

No, a tuxedo would not be appropriate for any development job because you would be severely overdressed.

Other options that would be inappropriate:

1. Swim trunks or bikini
2. Clown suit
3. Uniform of any kind
4. Advertising sandwich board
5. Any sort of mask.
6. Hat that has YOLO written on it.
7. Wet suit with swim fins.

Comment: I dunno, I've seen some pretty snappy sandwich boards...

Comment: Ah, inappropriate for a development job.  Was initially thinking #2 might be okay for some circus positions.

Comment: A military uniform would be appropriate for someone currently in the military who is expecting to get out very shortly and interviewing for a civilian job especially at a military contractor.I've interviewed military personnel on occasion in uniform, it is what they are required to wear to work after all.

Comment: What about a Batman costume? They do say you should dress for the job you want.

Comment: @HorusKol If you want to be batman, it's more about the ability to take down bad guys than it is about the costume, so as long as you got those skills the outfit will work itself out...

Comment: Rubber duck however are allowed.

Comment: Damn bought already this awesome [pig mask](http://orig10.deviantart.net/2a8b/f/2013/049/2/c/paintedpighead_by_so_full_of_stars-d5vdq7q.png) for my next interview...

Comment: @Artery reminds me of the game Manhunt. I think however you'll do just fine in an interview with that mask. Just remember to take a gun and shout loudly. They'll give you the job there and then.

Comment: @Bugs It's actually from Hotline Miami ;) Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Not merely overdressed, but wrongly dressed. Tuxedos are evening wear. Do not wear tuxedos during the day. This is worse than just wearing a suit to a khakis-and-polo interview.

Comment: Please add "hat that has YOLO written on it" to the list. Also is not appropriate.

Comment: @DanielJames Good call

Comment: And remember, quality edits that improve answers are encouraged on Stack Exchange.  :)

Comment: The Dowager Countess of Downton Abbey recommends a dressing gown or pyjamas [here at 2:50](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvqgboWKV9E) ;o)

Comment: @ChristopherEstep considering the substantial edit, you may need to review your answer.

Comment: @Walfrat I'll look it over and probably do that. thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 17):

If you're auditioning for an orchestra, a tuxedo would be appropriate. Depending on the instrument, the jacket would be left unbottoned to avoid bunching in the front (ie. trombone) or pulling on the buttons (ie. mallet percussion). Soloists tend to wear suits, but tuxedo is typical performance attire for just about every professional orchestra in the world.

For an office job interview, however, a tuxedo is perhaps a bit too formal. You'll definitely be remembered, but not for your technical prowess or people skills.

Comment: I can't imagine any musicians I know turning uo for an orchestral audition wearing a tux. Unless, maybe, they skipped out of a wedding party to attend.

Comment: Might be a regional thing. Definitely saw a lot of auditioners wearing tuxes in Boston. I guess it depends on where they fall on the formality scale, anywhere between "low brass" and "oboist".

Answer (score 5):

> However I do not have an appropriate business suit but I do have a Tuxedo jacket and several different options of formal pants and vests. Would it be acceptable if I wore this to an interview for a technical job?

**NO!** As most of the other answers here already say, a tuxedo is *not* appropriate business attire.

> Is doing this likely to cause any problems?

Wearing formal evening wear to a technical job would send a strong message that you don't understand how to match your behavior to a situation. Someone who was very generous might just put it down to a quirky fashion sense, but many would have a hard time looking past that faux pas even if you ace the rest of the interview. First impressions mean a lot, and overdressing can put you just as out of place as underdressing.

In other words, nobody is going to offer you a job because you dressed appropriately, but there's a good chance that dressing inappropriately could prevent them from making an offer that they otherwise would have.

Don't despair. You don't necessarily need to run out and drop a pile of cash that you may not have on a suit that you may never wear again. A *nice* pair of khaki pants, a clean, neatly pressed button-down shirt, real shoes (not sneakers), and a nice tie would make you perfectly presentable for most tech interviews, at least in most US companies that aren't banks or investment firms.

And just to state the obvious, make sure that you're well-groomed: get a haircut, shave (or trim, if you wear a beard), shower, brush your teeth, make sure your shoes are tied, match your belt to your shoes (they should be approximately the same color), and so on. These things don't cost much, and a well groomed candidate in jeans and a polo shirt will beat a messy candidate in a 3-piece suit hands down.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph. I never went into what you should wear. One thing I would say is it's good to invest in a suit for inteviews. You can wear the same one to different interviews. I did this when I first started out but as it happened I continued to wear them for work.

Comment: Agree -- I'd say it's good to invest in a suit, period. Formal occasions come up from time to time (weddings, funerals, work events outside the office, client meetings, etc.) and it's important to be able to dress right for such things.

Answer (score 1):

I know there are answers already, but they more so focus on the tuxedo part.

Generally, in interviews--much like sales--you want to be "a notch above" what the expected standard level of dress is for your employer or client.

So, retail store or call center? Maybe a nice dress shirt or polo with nice khakis. Job at a government or financial institution? Suit.

The level of dress depends on the employer, industry and even the area you'll be interviewing in.